# CakePHP - toMany relationship not working with UUIDs

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have the following model class:

```
class Property extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Property';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Inventory' => array(
            'className' => 'Inventory',
            'foreignKey' => 'property_id'
        )
    );
}
```

My database schema is set so that the id fields are all set to CHAR(36) so that CakePHP generates UUIDs for each entity. When I attempt to perform a find on my Property entity, it doesn't seem to be adding the necessary join to retrieve any related Inventories. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use cake bake console to build models from database ? Usually I'm using cake bake console and I have no trouble with relationships and UUIDs on Char(36) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be somewhat stupid.

I'd migrated this from a CakePHP 2.0 install to a CakePHP 1.3 install (couldn't update PHP on the server I was using), and all of my model classes still had uppercase first characters. Changing the file from Property.php to property.php fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

UUIDs will have nothing to do with it, I have a very similar model setup and use UUIDs everywhere.

You technically don't need those `className` and `foreignKey` declarations in there, as you seem to be following the CakePHP convention :)

I'd remove those lines, check your database for actual inventories with product IDs. If not, post the `find()`s you're doing.

Comment: I've changed the relationship to simply $hasMany = 'Inventory', and there's definitely an inventory with a property_id matching a property. My find is simply $this->Property->find('all') at the moment. The SQL query log shows that it's performing a SELECT on the properties table, but there's no JOINs or other queries on the inventories table. Strange!